# Google auto Places giving places suggestion very slow

Tags: react-native

I am making a react native application which needs the GooglePlacesSuggestion in react native. So I used a package:

`react-native-google-places-autocomplete`
And here is the code :

```
<View style = {{margin:10,padding:20,flex:1}}>
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Search'
            minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
            listViewDisplayed='auto'    // true/false/undefined
            fetchDetails={true}
            renderDescription={row => row.description} // custom description render
            onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
         //  ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(data),ToastAndroid.LONG)

                let city = details.address_components[0].long_name
                let lat = details.geometry.location.lat
                let lng = details.geometry.location.lng
                let full_addr= details.formatted_address

            }}

            getDefaultValue={() => ''}

            query={{

                key: 'AIzaSyB-q60XaNf5nsz5678e1jaRg0KTs5Q1nPi2Zk',
                language: 'en', // language of the results
                types: 'geocode' // default: 'geocode'
            }}

            styles={{
                textInputContainer: {
                    width: '100%'
                },
                description: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }}


            nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch

            GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
                }}
            GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{

                rankby: 'distance',
                types: 'food'
            }}

            filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={[ 'political','administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities


            debounce={200} // debounce the requests in ms. Set to 0 to remove debounce. By default 0ms.

        />
            </View>
```

But there arise two problems from the above code. While typing any places I get a very slow response, I mean that after typing a character or word for places it took 2-3 second to display the result and sometimes it does not display any result why? Also if I want to search address based on road name and area name then it doesn't give me any suggestions. Why? I am stuck I both these problem kindly help me in both the issue. Thanks in  advance